# Sequelize - ORDER BY count of associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sql-order-by, associations, has-many

I have two models, Company and Employee. The association is like Company hasMany Employee. Employee belongsTo Company.

I have to list all the Companies ordered by count of associations it have in the descending order.

My function is like following,

```
function get() {
     return Company.findAndCountAll({
       where: { status: Active }, 
       include: [
      {
        model: Employee,
        as: 'employees'
      }
    ],
     }).then((companies) => {
         return companies
      })
}
```

What can I give in order so that I can get list of companies based on count of associations(Employees) in descending order.

Please help me out in this...

I have tried as below. but it is throwing error like ***invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table companies.***

```
function get() {
     return Company.findAndCountAll({
       where: { status: Active }, 
       include: [
      {
        model: Employee,
        as: 'employees'
      }
    ],
     attributes: [
        [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE employees.company_id = companies.id)'), 'employeesCount']
    ],
    order: [[Sequelize.literal('employeesCount'), 'DESC']],
     }).then((companies) => {
         return companies
      })
}
```

where companies is the table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Please replace your **fieldName** with **sortField**

```
function get() {
     return Company.findAndCountAll({
       where: { status: Active }, 
       include: [
      {
        model: Employee,
        as: 'employees'
      }
    ],
    order: [[sortField, 'DESC']]
     }).then((companies) => {
         return companies
      })
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have a field for employees_count in the company table